Sleep settings get overwritten on Fedora 40
I'm using Fedora 40, KDE 6.1.4. My problem is that the "Power Management" configuration gets overwritten from somewhere.
I'm using "System Settings" > "Power Management" > "Suspend Session" to enable sleep after x minutes of inactivity and it works for about a day. After that it gets overwritten from somewhere and the computer never sleeps on idle. The overwritten configuration is not reflected in "System Settings" - it shows my original configuration. So to re-enable sleep on idle, I cycle the configuration in "System Settings".

I've done some googling, but I'm still confused about how to start troubleshooting this issue. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks.
